# Rails using state machine in polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-5, state-machine

I have this polymorphic model.

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: true, optional: false


  state_machine :is_status, initial: :pending do
    transition pending: :approved, on: %i[approve]
    transition pending: :cancelled, on: %i[cancel]
  end
end
```

and other two models

```
class Invoice < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :notes, as: :notable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :notes, as: :notable, dependent: :destroy
end
```

As you can see I'm attaching the note in two models its either person or invoice. and also using state machine. The scenario is I want to use the state machine in `invoice` only? is this possible.
so. if my notable_type is "Invoice". I got my status is "pending" else if is Person I got status: nil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you create a new model that encapsulates the behavior of the state machine and then attach that model to the invoice.

If the state machine is intended to represent the state of an Invoice then make it so InvoiceState `belongs_to` Invoice and Invoice `has_one` InvoiceState.

On the other hand, if you want to use this state machine to represent the more general concept of completeness then name it something appropriately generic (TransactionState, etc.) and attach it via a polymorphic relationship, like Note.

What I describe might look like this:

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: true, optional: false
end

class Person < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :notes, as: :notable, dependent: :destroy
end

class Invoice < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :notes, as: :notable, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :invoice_state, dependent: :destroy
end

class InvoiceState < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :invoice, optional: false

  state_machine :status, initial: :pending do
    transition pending: :approved, on: %i[approve]
    transition pending: :cancelled, on: %i[cancel]
  end
end
```

Comment: its looks clean to me. but meaning i will create one table invoice state with one column name is_status???

Comment: in addition to is_status, the InvoiceState table needs a column for its own primary key (id) and a column for the invoice foreign key (invoice_id)

Comment: yes i know the reference id that you mean. im try to apply this in my project as you can see. my example is just my replicate. give me time to apply this in my real project and accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you can pass `notable_type` == `Invoice` is a condition to the state machine to filter other notable_types

Comment: can you give an example?

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to AASM gem. 
https://github.com/aasm/aasm
.This will not only help you in adding guard methods to all the transitions, but also before and after callbacks.

You can also add a AASM hook method and set the state there. For example:-

```
class Note < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :notable, polymorphic: true, optional: false
  include AASM
  aasm do
    state :pending
    state :approved
    state :cancelled
    event :approve do
      transitions from: :pending, to: :approved, before: some_method, after: some_method1
    end
    event :cancel do
      transitions from: :pending, to: :cancelled, before: some_method2, after: some_method3
    end
  end
    def aasm_ensure_initial_state
      if notable_type == "Invoice"
        self.aasm_state = :pending
      else
        self.aasm_state = nil
      end
    end
    def some_method
        puts "Some actions can be taken here."
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: let me check this

Comment: where shall i put the 'some_method'

Comment: you can put the some_method definition after the aasm block. I am updating the above description and adding some_method too.